# Does the task still survive when the main thread that creates it has been killed in c#?

Tags: c#, task

I have a main thread that creates a task using:

```
new TaskFactory(cancellationToken).StartNew(() => DoSomething(cancellationToken), 
                                            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

I wonder if the task still survive when the main thread that creates the task has been killed in c#.

Comment: I tried and found the task was killed when my main thread was gone. As the one I used for test is only in a windows service, I wonder if this is globally correct on all cases(e.g. UI).

Comment: Well done.  See Rich's fine answer.  Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a process' main thread is terminated, the process aborts. When a process is killed, all threads (and other owned resources) are closed/terminated/killed also.

Therefore, if your process' main thread created a worker thread and the main thread is killed, the worker thread is also terminated.

Don't be confused by the `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` enum - this is just an indicator to the underlying thread-pool manager that it might want to create this thread outside the normal constraints on maximum thread-pool size.

Comment: This is more straightforward answer.Thanks.

Comment: Glad it made sense :) Note: This is why forcibly killing a process that may otherwise be hung/unresponsive often unlocks/unblocks/releases resources like threads, files, folders, sockets, etc. and frees the associated memory for re-use elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If AppDomain (usually equal to process) survives "killing" of the thread that created the task then task will continue to exist.

What happens when task try to finish depends on synchronization context - if it had to continue on aborted thread it will throw/hang, if it can continue on thread pool thread than task will be able to finish.

Note that usually for UI based apps aborting main thread means at least stopping event loop which will result in process to be considered "unresponsive" and possibly killed.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks. If you can attach some links(e.g. msdn) with more details that would be great.