# Thread interrupting a task in another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I know that method `Wait` ensures that thread in which method `Wait` was called waits for the task to complete. In my example, the main thread terminates before the task on the other thread terminates.

**Question**: When the main thread stops working, what happens inside at the environment level with another task in another thread in general terms? Task in other thread it forcibly interrupted by the main thread?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task task = new Task(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    Console.WriteLine("Task work");
                }
            });

            task.Start();
           
            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            //task.Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean specifically with "inside at the environment level", but yes, that thread is forcibly killed when the main thread exits. You can also use task.RunSynchronously() instead of task.Wait().

Comment: The `task.Wait()` would wait for the task to end, but your task never ends so it just waits forever.

Comment: A foreground thread will keep the process alive. A background thread will be aborted. See [Thread.IsBackground](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.isbackground?view=net-6.0)

Comment: @Enigmativity, The task will complete without Wait(). Check. It will be interrupted by the main thread. It is a fact.

Comment: Thanks to all. I just needed confirmation that the calling thread aborts the task on another thread if I don't wait and if the main thread ends.

Comment: @user18273286 - My comment was about adding the `task.Wait()`. I didn't say anything about what would happen if it wasn't there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32262236/6271132